# Tag is too long

Tags: support, tags

Found a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/109828/who-was-the-old-lady-in-the-woods-in-i-dont-feel-at-home-in-this-world-anymore) about a movie called [I Don't Feel at Home in This World Anymore](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5710514/).
When I tried to edit the question to include movie name, I see an error saying movie title exceeded the maximum allowed limit.

Has this happen before for any movie?

What can we do about this(if any)?

[image]

Comment: It happens all the time, previosuly limit was 25. Solution is come up with a tag which is meanigfyl and still fit, for now I made the tag [tag:i-dont-feel-at-home-in-this-world]

Comment: yeah :)  but what if when another movie named  *i-dont-feel-at-home-in-this-world* in future?

Comment: That will be big coincidence. For now, it's unique and identifiable.